# Module has no exported member 'Md5'?

Tags: angular, typescript, md5

So basically I import:

```js
import { Md5 } from 'ts-md5/dist/md5';
```

But it says that:

```
Module has no exported member Md5?
```

But it works fine, problem is that it is giving me an error while compiling.

I changed it to lowercase md5 like:

```js
import { md5 } from 'ts-md5/dist/md5';
```

But now my function doesnt work:

```js
 hashIt(email: string){
    this.hashString = md5.hashStr(email);
    console.log(this.hashString);
  }
```

It says:

```
Property 'hashStr' does not exist on type '(string : any) => string'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure it is installed `npm install --save ts-md5`.
 Import it directly in the component where you have to use it:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Md5} from 'ts-md5/dist/md5';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  md5 = new Md5();
  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.md5.appendStr('hello').end());
  }

}
```

Working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5wwrk4?file=src/app/app.component.ts), if still not working, try `npm uninstall ts-md5` then `npm install --save ts-md5`